# Google Chrome video not playing- Json response with html video tag

Tags: javascript, json, html, google-chrome, video

I have written an html page which loads the video tag dynamically from a json file. I am using Chrome 50 for this. The response comes back successfully. When I use the developer tools of chrome I can see the video tag on the page. However the video does not play. I have added autoplay attribute as well to the video tag. I am using the below:

`<video autoplay> <source src="......."></source> </video>`

In the developer tools in XHR, I can see the following:

1. Request sent for JSON file
2. Response returns the Json response which contains html video tag

However no further request is sent for the video and in the media tab the video is not present.

Can you let me know is this an issue with Chrome and how to solve it?

Comment: Are you sure the video is in a format chrome can play?

Answer (score 0):

you don't need the `<source>`-Tag

try this:

```
<video autoplay src="......."></video>
```

this worked for me.